# Why is this code not working in Xcode 4.5 while it use to work on Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode4.5

Why is this code not working in Xcode 4.5 (with the ipad 6.0 simulator) while it use to work on Xcode 4.4.(with ipad simulator 5.1)

```
- (IBAction)capitalDButtonTwo:(id)sender {
    if ([capitalDResultLabelTwo text] == @"+") {
        [capitalDResultLabelTwo setText:@"0"];
    } else {
        [capitalDResultLabelTwo setText:@"+"];
    }
}
```

this is a button that sets the text in a label in the same view to "+" the first time it is pressed then set the text to "0" then to "+" every time it is pressed after that. I wonder what is so different from one version to the other for this simple code not to work

Comment: Mine is working _except_ for the `sender` part. I am using the `sender.view` and it says `Property 'view' not found on object type 'id'`. Still trying to find out why though.

Comment: @AnnaFortuna You need to cast `id` to the actual type that you know it is, for example `((UILabel *)id).text = @"Hello";`.  I'm confused when you say yours is working; do you mean you use this exact same code fragment?  If so, you need to see my answer, below.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't work in either Xcode version.  You are not comparing strings correctly:

The statement `[capitalDResultLabelTwo text] == @"+"` tests if two `NSString` objects are the exact same object.  What you intended, I'm sure, is to test if the *content* of the label is the same as `"+"`, and hence you need to use `[NSString isEqualToString:]`:

```
- (IBAction)capitalDButtonTwo:(id)sender {
    if ([[capitalDResultLabelTwo text] isEqualToString:@"+"]) {
        [capitalDResultLabelTwo setText:@"0"];
    } else {
        [capitalDResultLabelTwo setText:@"+"];
    }
}
```

Comment: well, it seems to behave as expected in xcode 4.4 (simulator 5.1), but yes, you are right #trojanfoe; i am so used to using (==) from python. I am very new to programming(probably obvious). I will try your suggestion though thanks!